# Water pressure totally gone after turning off to repair

Tags: water, water-pressure

We turned our water main off and on repeatedlly and now all pressure is gone. Help please.

Comment: **all pressure** literally means that you have absolutely no water flowing, is this the case? Please describe the exact issue and circumstances. Why did you happen to turn the main on and off a bunch of times, just for fun?

Comment: Sometimes turning off the main causes debris to get dislodged. Most common problem is it clogs up the aerators at faucets. Try to remove the aerators to see if that helps. If so then clean the aerators.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - the valve (rarely operated) broke when operated and is not opening.

Option 2 - deposits, disturbed by closing the valve and draining the plumbing, have plugged the pipes.

For option 2, open whatever valves are nearest the valve, or open up unions and flush out whatever glop may be there if ANY water flows - and/or run a stiff wire into the pipe (not through valves, but if opened at unions.)

For option 1, the main valve will need to be replaced.

If there is absolutely no water flow at all, bet on option 1.

Comment: It sounds like option 1 if the knob turns freely. This is fairly common on older gate valves. The valve internals were likely corroded, and the screw which retracts the gate most likely sheared off. To get this fixed, you will have to contact the city and have them shut the water supply off at the curb, then the valve can be replaced. My recommendation would be to replace it will a quality ball valve. They are more reliable, and less likely to get stuck open or closed.